# Converting an image into a cartoon using php image magick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

Im wondering does anyone know of any good tutorials that can help me learn to convert a human image to a cartoon using php image magick.

I have found this link, http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cartoon/

but there are two issue.

1. I'm not overly impressed with the results, I would imagine theres room for improvement
2. The script isnt PHP , but perhaps Ill have to learn to convert it myself and work from there.

I have another cartoonize class written in php that doesnt use image magick, but the results arent great, and I prefer image magick as it seems cleaner and faster.

Thank you

Comment: This is a little broad. Can you post a sample image(s) of what your expecting, and what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run bash shell scripts containing Imagemagick commands from PHP exec().

You might like this approach better, but I have no idea how they do it.  See http://cartoon.pho.to/